# push json items into array

Tags: jquery, jsonp

How do I push items returned from this json file into an array called places:

```
var places = [];

$.ajax({    
    url: "http://www.example.com/places.json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(data, status) {
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            places = item.latitude+','+ item.longitude;    
        });
    },
    error: function() {
        $("#status").html('There was an error loading the data.');
    }
});
```

Comment: Worked :O) How can I put all of this in a function called getPlaces and make it return the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply `push` the data onto the array like so:

```
places.push(item.latitude+','+ item.longitude);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(data, status) {
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        places.push( item.latitude+','+ item.longitude );
    });
},
```

Comment: The OP had `places` already declared as an empty array outside the success function, so presumably doesn't want it as a local variable.

Comment: ah ok, didn't see that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var places = [];

$.ajax({    
  url: "http://www.example.com/places.json",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  timeout: 5000,
  success: function(data, status) {
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        var place = item.latitude+','+ item.longitude;
        places.push(place);
    });
  },
  error: function() {
    $("#status").html('There was an error loading the data.');
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey, does the places variable still have same value if I called it outside $.ajax() scope? or is it empty? I mean, something like this: $.ajax({...}); console.log(places.length), it prints 0??

Comment: @ladiesman Yes, it still has a value, however, it appears that the success callback has not yet been called, which is why the output is 0. Add your logging into the success callback to see the length increment.